# Free Account Azure version HDInsight and cores issue

Tags: azure, hadoop, microsoft

I am using an Free Azure account version and I am trying to create the resources needed to put in place HDInsight. I have done it twice, but in order to spare the time/money I have available, I have deleted the resource group. Unortunately now that I am trying to recreate the cluster, Azure prevents me saying I don't have enough cores. That's strange as before this worked perfectly. Do you have any suggestion? Azure was supposed to work at least for other 25 days...
If you can help me, I am thankful
Thank you
Nicola

Answer (score 0):

The majority of Azure subscriptions have a fixed number (quota) of cores allocated to them. This is for resource management (to avoid exceeding the capacity of a region) and to prevent abuse. From experience, a committed spend (enterprise) subscription is usually allocated 20 cores and will be increased on request via Microsoft Support.

I suspect that a free or trial subscription has a much smaller quota which is what you are experiencing. I doubt Microsoft will increase the quota on the free or trial account. The exception possibly being if your account is linked to your Visual Studio paid subscription.

**Update**
I cannot see the picture mentioned in your answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I'm a little bit puzzled on this, because the account worked perfectly three days ago, while all of sudden it started giving this message.
Indeed it seems that I do not have not even one core available. Look at the picture attached.
That's very strange to me. Kind Regards
Nicola